# Property validation failure in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

The following snippet is from a Cloudformation formation template:

```
...
LambdaFunctionAssociations:
  - !If
    - ProtectDistribution
    -
      - EventType: viewer-request
        LambdaFunctionARN: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeProtection.Outputs.CheckAuthHandler
      - EventType: origin-response
        LambdaFunctionARN: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeProtection.Outputs.HttpHeadersHandler
    - !Ref AWS::NoValue
...
```

It's a part of a `DefaultCacheBehavior` within a `DistributionConfig` of a CloudFront distribution. It's giving me this error when trying to create the stack:

`Property validation failure: [Value of property {/DistributionConfig/DefaultCacheBehavior/LambdaFunctionAssociations/0} does not match type {Object}]`

Where am I going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `- !If` condition of your code you have already declared the array before the if condition and if the condition gets true, `- - EventType: viewer-request` here you are again providing array, which is wrong.
You should try it this way,

```
...
LambdaFunctionAssociations:
  - !If
    - ProtectDistribution
    - EventType: viewer-request
      LambdaFunctionARN: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeProtection.Outputs.CheckAuthHandler
    - !Ref AWS::NoValue
  - !If
    - ProtectDistribution
    - EventType: origin-response
      LambdaFunctionARN: !GetAtt LambdaEdgeProtection.Outputs.HttpHeadersHandler
    - !Ref AWS::NoValue 
...
```